# enable core dump for existing process

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I'd like to enable core dumps for a process that I don't control the creation of. This process is started by some initialization script on startup, the process runs as the root user.

How can I enable core dumps (on process crash) for this process? I'd like to avoid a server reboot if possible.

System is Ubuntu